# How could I handle an asp.net mvc error AND use the same view from the controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, error-handling, tempdata

I have actions like this:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult New(Product product)
{
    try
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _productService.Create(product);
            TempData["success"] = "Product created successfully!";
            return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { product.Id });
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logger.Exception(e);
        TempData["error"] = "Oops, an error occurred! Please try again in a few moments.";
    }

    return View(product);
}
```

I want to take this error handling logic out of the methods. However, instead of the default [HandleError] way of doing things, instead of redirecting the user to another view in case of an error, it returns me the same view with a TempData["error"], and a notification will appear in the top of the same page.

How could I do this, delete all this try{}catch{} code and put this logic outside this action, for other actions as well?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [HandleError] and OnException to do what you want. Eg, to display a custom view:

```
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
        // Output a nice error page
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.IsCustomErrorEnabled)
        {
                filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
                this.View("Error").ExecuteResult(this.ControllerContext);
        }
}
```

I posted a little more info about this on my blog a while back:

http://blog.dantup.com/2009/04/aspnet-mvc-handleerror-attribute-custom.html